# Android ListView- Error on setListAdapter & getListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

i have the Following Code in MainAvtivity:

```
private DBOperations DataDBoperation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataDBoperation = new DBOperations(this);
        DataDBoperation.open();

        List values = DataDBoperation.getAllUserSIMs();

        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }
    public void addSim(View view) {

        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();

        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SIMsClass stud = DataDBoperation.addSIMs(text.getText().toString());

        adapter.add(stud);

    }

    public void deleteSim(View view) {

        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
        SIMsClass sim = null;

        if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
            sim = (SIMsClass) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
            DataDBoperation.deleteSIMs(sim);
            adapter.remove(sim);
        }

    }

    public void addPassword(View view) {

        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();

        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        PasswordClass stud = DataDBoperation.addPassword(text.getText().toString());

        adapter.add(stud);

    }
```

and here is the layoun XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="113dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:onClick="addSim"
        android:text="Add New" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:onClick="deleteSim"
        android:text="Delete First" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deleteBtn" >
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/passwordBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:onClick="addPassword"
        android:text="@string/password" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***ERROR:***
The method is setListAdapter(Adapter) undefined for the type MainActivity.
The method is getListAdapter(Adapter) undefined for the type MainActivity.

Comment: does your activity class extend `ListActivity` or `Activity`?

Comment: check the updated answ i hve posted.. may b it will help..

Comment: you can check solution at<br/> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897086/i-get-error-when-retrive-items-from-arrayadapter-any-solution-for-that?noredirect=1#comment57530770_34897086

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`. `setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity`. Same for `getListAdapter`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: also if you are extending `SherlockListActivity` it would be ok

Answer (score 2):

if you r extending only activity thn u need to get listview from view which u set as a setcontentview

and its bttr to design and gve id(for understanding multiple list identification) of listview in xml layout like

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deleteBtn" >
</ListView>
```

and from activity where you r setting adapter need to get listview 
and thn set adapter to the listview. u gt error bcz tht method u cn override if u extend ListActivity or ListFragment. bt ASFIK its simple activity u used

so once try like

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataDBoperation = new DBOperations(this);
        DataDBoperation.open();

        List values = DataDBoperation.getAllUserSIMs();

        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView.

// get your listview from layout "(R.layout.activity_main)"
// i hve gvn own id not android default .. for undestanding. you can use the id which u used
             ListView list = findViewById(R.id.listScreen);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

and for more details check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) or [this](http://androidexample.com/Create_Listview_With_ListActivity_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=66&aaid=91)